# Twilio Studio Function to Send Voicemail URL

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using Twilio Studio for to collect messages for our small church. When someone records a voicemail, I am using a function to send the recording URL to the group members. Here is what that function looks like currently:

```
var groupmembers = [
{
    name: 'Person1',
    number: '+11111111111'
},
{
    name: 'Person2',
    number: '+11111111111'
}
];

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  groupmembers.forEach(function(member) {

 // Now, forward on the message to the group member, using the sender's name 
twiml.message(`Text from ${event.senderFrom}: ${event.senderMessage}`, {
    to: member.number
});   
  })

  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

This gives me a '12200 Schema validation warning' with the detail: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Message'. One of '{Play

I'm fairly sure the issue is because I am trying to send an SMS during a call but I am not sure how to update my TWIML or Studio flow to accommodate for this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the REST API rather then TwiML in this case. You could use code similar to what is shown below to do this.

Make sure to check the box below, under [Function Config](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure) for your Function,

[image]

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

  let groupMembers = [
    {
        name: 'Person1',
        number: '+14701111111'
    },
    {
        name: 'Person2',
        number: '+18082222222'
    },
    {
        name: 'Person3',
        number: '+18021111111'
    }
  ];    

  function sendSMS(member) {
    return twilioClient.messages.create({
      from: '+13054444444',
      to: member.number,
      body: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }

  let promises = [];

  groupMembers.forEach((member) => {
  console.log(member);
  promises.push(sendSMS(member));
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((values) => {
      console.log(values);
      callback(null,"Success");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      callback("Failure");
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm, and the code matches nearly exactly, accounting for updating the SMS numbers to match your own and the associated CallerID the messages are sent from? Clearly it doesn't like something with the `twilioClient.messages.create` but don't have the same issue on my side :(

Comment: Thanks Alan! Just can't seem to figure out how to access the variables being passed for the number and voicemail URL to merge into the outgoing SMS message.

Comment: I think maybe you typed `client.message.create` instead of `client.messages.create` (plural). Also, when you call the Studio Run Function Widget, make sure you pass in the Recorded Voicemail URL via the liquid (mustache template syntax - `widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.RecordingUrl` - changing `MY_WIDGET_NAME` with whatever you called your widget). You can access it from your function via the event object, something like `let myReqURL = event.myPassedInValue`. The same for the number which is passed via the Trigger Widget of your Studio Flow `{{trigger.call.Caller}}`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much Alan!